# Getting value after button click with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to get a value that is given by the website after a click on a button.

Here is the website: https://www.4devs.com.br/gerador_de_cpf

You can see that there is a button called "Gerar CPF", this button provides a number that appears after the click.

My current script opens the browser and get the value, but I'm getting the value from the page before the click, so the value is empty. I would like to know if it is possible to get the value after the click on the button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.4devs.com.br/gerador_de_cpf"

def open_browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/felipe/Downloads/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('bt_gerar_cpf').click()

def get_cpf():
    response = get(url)

    page_with_cpf = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    cpf = page_with_cpf.find("div", {"id": "texto_cpf"}).text

    print("The value is: " + cpf)


open_browser()
get_cpf()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`open_browser` and `get_cpf` are absolutely not related to each other...

Actually you don't need `get_cpf` at all. Just wait for text after clicking the button:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

def open_browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/felipe/Downloads/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('bt_gerar_cpf').click()
    text_field = driver.find_element_by_id('texto_cpf')
    text = wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: not text_field.text == 'Gerando...' and text_field.text)
    return text

print(open_browser())
```

*Update*

The same with requests:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.4devs.com.br/ferramentas_online.php'
data = {'acao': 'gerar_cpf', 'pontuacao': 'S'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: You are right, they are not related. But I tried your code here and still empty value

Comment: @Felipe , did you try initial answer or last updated? Still no output? I tried it couple times and got required output...

Comment: I tried the last updated, here is the output: <div class="output-txt" id="texto_cpf" onclick="fourdevs.selectText(this)"></div>

Comment: @Felipe , hmm... My code definitely cannot return `div` node... I think you use it incorrectly. Just do `print(open_browser())` to get value

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg , I'm not sure what do you mean... `until` returns function output (*anything*) passed as argument as soon as it become true. In this case it returns the *last condition (`text_field.text`) - string*. If to replace conditions it will return `not text_field.text == 'Gerando...'` (`True`) - *boolean*. But in none cases it might return `WebElement`

Comment: It is possible to do the same thing using scrapy-splash?

Comment: @Felipe , I don't use Scrapy, so I can't provide you with appropriate code. Check updated answer

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use requests and BeautifulSoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.4devs.com.br/gerador_de_cpf"

def get_cpf():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/felipe/Downloads/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('bt_gerar_cpf').click()
    sleep(10)
    text=driver.find_element_by_id('texto_cpf').text
    print(text)
get_cpf()
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a While loop until text changes?

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.4devs.com.br/gerador_de_cpf"

def get_value():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('bt_gerar_cpf').click()
    while driver.find_element_by_id('texto_cpf').text == 'Gerando...':
        continue
    val = driver.find_element_by_id('texto_cpf').text
    driver.quit()
    return val

print(get_value())
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this website that does exactly the same thing.

https://4devs.net.br/gerador-cpf

But to get the "gerar cpf" action with selenium, you can inspect the HTML source code with a browser and click on "copy XPath for this element".

It is much simpler than manually searching for the elements in the page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).