# How do I use BeautifulSoup in python to scrape all the results of a website where all results are on one page?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all search results from https://www.carmax.com/cars/all. If you go to the website, you see that at the bottom of the results there is a button to show more results, and this would continue until there are no more results. I'm not sure how to scrape data from all the results and then check that it is completed. The code I have below works for what initially shows up on the results page.

Thanks for any help here!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
html = requests.get("https://www.carmax.com/cars/all",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

tiles = soup.find_all('div', class_='car-tile')

n = 0
for tile in tiles:
    yearmake = tile.find('span', class_='year-make').text.strip()
    modeltrim = tile.find('span', class_='model-trim').text.strip()
    print('TILE ' + str(n) + ': ym=' + yearmake + ', mt=' + modeltrim)
    n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough reputation to reply yet, but maybe use this post for guidance:
[Getting value after button click with BeautifulSoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973423/getting-value-after-button-click-with-beautifulsoup-python)

**Note**: This method requires you to use the [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/).

The main idea is that you can click that button to load more results,
so find the **id** of that button and click it.
Also, as the suggestion in the post I've linked to notes,
you can add some `sleep`s to allow the new results to load and for the "see more matches" option to reappear.

Your `while` loop condition can check if the number of `car-tile` divs is changing.
Once it is not changing after a click, you can assume that you've collected all of the results.

There may also be a scenario where after you fetch all of the results, the button will no longer appear;
in which case that can be another exit condition for your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

i would use selenium to first load everything up before scraping it. This is what i tried and got to the bottom of the page hence the full data is now available to scrape. Sorry for the poor coding, I'm quite new as well.

chrome driver can get from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from time import sleep

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="YOUR DRIVER PATH HERE", chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.carmax.com/cars/all")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)


for i in range(100):
    # scroll to bottom
    see_more_cars = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="see-more"]/div')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", see_more_cars)
    try:
        # if button available to see more cars, click it
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a'))).click()
        sleep(10)
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        # if button NOT available to see more cars, wait then click
        sleep(10)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", see_more_cars)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a'))).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # if button no longer available, break
        break
```